# ECDSA public key compressed to pem format java

Tags: java, bouncycastle, public-key, ecdsa

I have compressed public keys for `ECDSA` for curve `secp256k1`

> 0252972572d465d016d4c501887b8df303eee3ed602c056b1eb09260dfa0da0ab2
> 0318ed2e1ec629e2d3dae7be1103d4f911c24e0c80e70038f5eb5548245c475f50

I need to convert these to pem format in same compressed way using java. I tried to write pem format using `SubjectPublicKeyInfo`. But it is not giving me expected results.

Comment: What kind of compression is that? It doesn't seem to be gzip

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option is BouncyCastle and the following implementation:

```java
import java.io.StringWriter;
import java.util.HexFormat;
import org.bouncycastle.asn1.x9.X9ObjectIdentifiers;
import org.bouncycastle.util.io.pem.PemObject;
import org.bouncycastle.util.io.pem.PemWriter;
import org.bouncycastle.asn1.sec.SECObjectIdentifiers;
import org.bouncycastle.asn1.x509.AlgorithmIdentifier;
import org.bouncycastle.asn1.x509.SubjectPublicKeyInfo;
...
byte[] compressedKey = HexFormat.of().parseHex("03CD26952CFFB40A3C2B7E41BE80F02F8A21BA73958ED22276CC28D7BBAA1AA07A");
AlgorithmIdentifier algId = new AlgorithmIdentifier(X9ObjectIdentifiers.id_ecPublicKey, SECObjectIdentifiers.secp256k1);
SubjectPublicKeyInfo subjectPublicKeyInfo = new SubjectPublicKeyInfo(algId, compressedKey);
StringWriter sw = new StringWriter(); 
try (PemWriter pw = new PemWriter(sw)) {
    pw.writeObject (new PemObject ("PUBLIC KEY", subjectPublicKeyInfo.getEncoded("DER")));  
}
System.out.println(sw.toString());
```

This results e.g. for the compressed key:

```
0252972572d465d016d4c501887b8df303eee3ed602c056b1eb09260dfa0da0ab2
```

in the following X.509/SPKI PEM key:

```
-----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----
MDYwEAYHKoZIzj0CAQYFK4EEAAoDIgACUpclctRl0BbUxQGIe43zA+7j7WAsBWse
sJJg36DaCrI=
-----END PUBLIC KEY-----
```

The PEM key can be loaded with an ASN.1 parser, e.g. https://lapo.it/asn1js/. The encapsulated key corresponds to the compressed key.

---

Note that the import of an X.509/SPKI EC key with a compressed key is not always supported (e.g. JCA/JCE: *Invalid EC key / Only uncompressed point format supported*):

```java
Security.addProvider(new BouncyCastleProvider()); // Commenting out causes an exception: Invalid EC key / Only uncompressed point format supported
String spkiDerWithCompressed = "MDYwEAYHKoZIzj0CAQYFK4EEAAoDIgADzSaVLP+0CjwrfkG+gPAviiG6c5WO0iJ2zCjXu6oaoHo=";
KeyFactory kf = KeyFactory.getInstance("EC");
X509EncodedKeySpec keySpecX509 = new X509EncodedKeySpec(Base64.getDecoder().decode(spkiDerWithCompressed));
PublicKey publicKey = (ECPublicKey) kf.generatePublic(keySpecX509);
String spkiDerWithUncompressed = Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(publicKey.getEncoded());
System.out.println(spkiDerWithUncompressed); // MFYwEAYHKoZIzj0CAQYFK4EEAAoDQgAEzSaVLP+0CjwrfkG+gPAviiG6c5WO0iJ2zCjXu6oaoHr7WDbGHaR3hDq6+PtVm4+G5gWiYCWrh3fxe4ahjeW3Sw==
```

---

For completeness: A conversion of the compressed key into an uncompressed key is possible with BouncyCastle, e.g.:

```java
import org.bouncycastle.asn1.x9.X9ECParameters;
import org.bouncycastle.asn1.x9.ECNamedCurveTable;
import org.bouncycastle.math.ec.ECPoint;
...     
byte[] compressedKey = HexFormat.of().parseHex("0252972572d465d016d4c501887b8df303eee3ed602c056b1eb09260dfa0da0ab2");
X9ECParameters x9Params = ECNamedCurveTable.getByName("secp256k1");
ECPoint ecpoint = x9Params.getCurve().decodePoint(compressedKey);
byte[] uncompressedKey = ecpoint.getEncoded(false);
```

An X.509/SPKI PEM key encapsulating the uncompressed key can be generated using the same code that was used for the compressed key.

Comment: So what kind of compression is used in that key?

Comment: @g00se - Compressed/Uncompressed key means in this context a format for a public EC key. A public EC key is an EC point (x, y). The concatenation of x and y coordinate preceded by a 0x04 byte is called uncompressed, the x coordinate preceded by a 0x02 (for an even y coordinate) or 0x03 (for an odd y coordinate) is called compressed format. So both posted keys are compressed EC keys, s. e.g. [here](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/a/70759).